# Xamarin.Forms: Bind navigationbar (header) to listview and make it scroll up and down with the list

Tags: listview, xamarin.forms

I am trying to achieve an affect I have seen on many apps - yet cannot seem to find a solution on google for it, or maybe I am phrasing it wrong?

You probably seen apps, where there is a big header (not neccessarely the navigation bar) that scrolls out of view when the listview inside that page is being scrolled down. As soon as the user scrolls up at any point inside the listview, the header scrolls back with the list view. I would like to achieve the same:

I have this listview:

```
 <flv:FlowListView  
                    Grid.Column="1"
                    FlowItemAppearing="listview_allAds_FlowItemAppearing"
                    FlowIsLoadingInfiniteEnabled="True"
                    Refreshing="listview_allAds_Refreshing"
                    FlowColumnCount="2"
                    IsPullToRefreshEnabled="True"
                    Margin="0,0,0,0"
                    VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Never"
                    FlowItemTapped="listview_allAds_FlowItemTapped"
                    HasUnevenRows="True"
                    x:Name="listview_allAds" >

                    <flv:FlowListView.FlowColumnTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>

                            <ContentView Padding="4,3,3,4">

<!-- contents-->
                            </ContentView>



                        </DataTemplate>
                    </flv:FlowListView.FlowColumnTemplate>
                </flv:FlowListView>
```

And this header:

```
        <ScrollView  BackgroundColor="#B9CAD4" Orientation="Horizontal" HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Never">
          
            <Grid Margin="0,5,0,5" ColumnSpacing="0">


                <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="auto"/>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="auto"/>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="auto"/>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="auto"/>
                </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

                <Grid Margin="2,0,2,0"  Grid.Column="0">
```

```
                </Grid>

            </Grid>
            


     


        </ScrollView>
```

But ofcourse, both layouts are fixed:

How would I bind the two layouts together that the scorll of one affects the other and reveals more space?

Thank you!

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You could set the [Header](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/user-interface/listview/customizing-list-appearance#headers-and-footers) of ListView . in your case you used the third part plugin . And you can also set it like following

```
<flv:FlowListView.Header>

   <!-- contents-->
   //set the content View of header here
 
</flv:FlowListView.Header>
```

Comment: Hello, thank you. This doesnt work thou. It sets a header to the listview, that is correct, but this header is really ON TOP the listview. If you are WAY down in the list view and jsut need the header back, you would have to scroll ALL THE WAY back up - but the point is for the layout to just come swooping in, wherever you are in the listview.

Comment: What effect did you want to achieve ? You could provide a gif .